# CDI: Why are there unsatisfied dependencies in the following setup?

Tags: cdi

Ear file:

```
ear
 +--lib
 |   +--API jar
 |   |     +-- com.foobar.Greeter.class (interface)
 |   |         (look, ma, no META-INF/beans.xml on purpose)
 |   |
 |   +--JAX-RS endpoint jar
 |         +-- com.foobar.GreeterResource.class (has @Inject Greeter greeter;)
 |         +-- META-INF/beans.xml
 |   
 +--EJB jar
 |   +-- com.foobar.GreeterBean implements com.foobar.Greeter (@Stateless, @Local)
 |   +-- META-INF/beans.xml
 |
 +--JAX-RS skinny war (no libs)
     +-- WEB-INF/beans.xml (maybe not necessary?)
     +-- WEB-INF/classes/com.foobar.Application 
                                   (empty subclass of JAX-RS Application)
```

To recap in English:

- API jar file.  Contains `Greeter` interface.  Present in `lib` directory.
- EJB jar file.  Contains a `@Stateless` `@Local` EJB that implements `Greeter`.  Also contains a `META-INF/beans.xml` file.  CDI [says this is necessary](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.0/html/packagingdeployment.html#beanarchive) to make this a bean archive.
- Skinny war.  Exists only to have an (empty) `Application` class in it to serve as the bootstrappy part of JAX-RS.  Endpoints are NOT located within.  Contains a `WEB-INF/beans.xml` file, though I confess I'm not sure this is necessary, since [by definition](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.0/html/packagingdeployment.html#beanarchive) `WEB-INF/beans.xml` marks only the `classes` directory (which here does not exist) as a bean archive.
- JAX-RS endpoint jar file.  This one's slightly weird.  Present in the **`.ear`** `lib` directory, so on the classpath, but not in the `.war` file's `lib` directory (on purpose).  Discovered—per the JAX-RS 1.1 specification—automatically by the JAX-RS application, so classes within it are probably in a kind of tug-of-war between JAX-RS and CDI.  `GreeterResource` contains `@Inject Greeter greeter;`.

Deploying this in GlassFish 3.1.2.2 (Weld 1.1.8) yields an unsatisfied dependency error for the `@Inject` location.  WTF?

Why?  The only `Greeter` instance in the whole application is an EJB implementation, which is in a bean archive.  The resource class is in a bean archive.  I read the specification as [saying that session beans automatically have their business local interfaces registered as bean types](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.0/html/implementation.html#sessionbeantypes).

Comment: simply because the Greeter interface isn't a register type, as a result it's not injectable.  your greeterimpl is injectable directly as that impl but not as the interface.  I'm actually a little surprised by the JAX-RS stuff, I wouldn't have expected that to get picked up since it seems like most impls want them to be in a WAR.

Comment: I thought that the local business interface exposed by a session bean (`Greeter` exposed by `GreeterBean`) was automatically a registered type: http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.0/html/implementation.html#sessionbeantypes.  No?

Comment: Regarding the JAX-RS stuff: Paul Sandoz and I had a go-around about this many moons ago.  The spec bug is here: https://java.net/jira/browse/JAX_RS_SPEC-278  The forum discussion is here: https://java.net/projects/javaee-spec/lists/users/archive/2012-10/message/27

Comment: Sorry, let me clarify.  Greeter is a registered type in your EJB-JAR.  It is not a registered type in your WAR.  EJB jars and WARs are both standalone running applications.  They don't share CDI context.  Your JAX-RS is being brought in to the WAR context, but your EJB is running in your EJB jar's context.

Comment: Oh, that's interesting. Could you kindly point me at the area of the CDI spec where the non-sharing of contexts is made clear? I'm not challenging—just genuinely curious and the spec is a bit of a haystack. :-)

Comment: No, but I think you're already aware of the issues.  CDI spec doesn't have any mentions of EARs.

Comment: Wait (feeling thick): so you're saying if I mix a `.war` and an EJB `.jar` and each uses `@Inject` to inject something in from "outside", I'm out of luck as far as the spec is concerned? Surely that's not the intent.

Comment: Sorry John, but I also think this must work. The 'Greeter' interface is available in the ClassLoader and the GreeterBean implements it. if you look up the Bean<GreeterBean> then you will see that getTypes() will also return {GreeterBean.class, Greeter.class, Object.class}. Thus it perfectly satisfies the injection point type Greeter. I rather think this is a pretty clear bug in GlassFish.