# @Inject a bean from an EJB project gives UnsatisfiedResolutionException

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, dependency-injection, cdi, websphere-8

I have two maven projects.

1. One is packaging type ejb, including a beans.xml in the /META-INF

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_0.xsd"
>
```

2. One is packaging type war, including a beans.xml in the /WEB-INF

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_0.xsd"
>
</beans>
```

These are then packaged into a single ear.

In my ejb project, I have a class `Banana`, and in the war project, I have a class `Monkey`.
I then try to run this in WAS 8.5, so it'll use JEE 6
However, when I try to `@Inject Banana cdiBanana` in the `Monkey` class, it fails.
It gives the message

> javax.enterprise.inject.UnsatisfiedResolutionException: Api type [org.food.Banana] is not found with the qualifiers
>   Qualifiers: [@javax.enterprise.inject.Default()]

When I make the `Banana` a `@Stateless` EJB, and give the `Monkey` a `@EJB Banana ejbBanana` it works.

Why wouldn't this work? And what should I do or try to make it work?

Maybe related to [CDI: Why are there unsatisfied dependencies in the following setup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18008321/cdi-why-are-there-unsatisfied-dependencies-in-the-following-setup) ?

Comment: Mark the banana with ```@Stateless``` and ```@Depedent```

Comment: Why `@Dependent`? Is that necessary? Why? (it doesn't seem necessary to me)

Comment: What container are you using? Is your ejb-jar deployed to WEB-INF/lib of the WAR file? what does the beans.xml look like for each package?  Please update your question with this info.

Comment: How did you set up `bean-discovery-mode` in your EJB modules `beans.xml`?

Comment: - on vacation now, so i'll update it when I have the code again...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now, I'll close this question.
It looks like the problem is the JEE6 spec.

- Running this in liberty (JEE7) it works fine.
- Running in Wildfly (JEE7) works fine
- Running in JBoss (JEE6) fails
- Running in WAS 8.5 (JEE6) fails.

Apparently, @Inject a bean from another Ejb-jar gives problems for the container.
When you use @EJB it works fine.